# Is the implementation of ThreadRAII correct in the Effective Modern C++ book?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Item 37 in the book illustrates an implementation of ThreadRAII, that either joins a thread or detaches it when it is destroyed. By declaring the destructor the compiler doesn’t generate the move operations, but in the book the author says that there’s no reason why they should not be movable and says that compilers would generate the right move operations and advises us to use the ‘= default’ implementation.

```
#include <thread>

class ThreadRAII
{
public:
    enum class DtorAction { join, detach };

    ThreadRAII(std::thread&& t, DtorAction a)
        : action(a)
        , t(std:: move(t))
    {}

    ~ThreadRAII()
    {
        if(t.joinable())
        {
            if(action == DtorAction::join)
                t.join();
            else
                t.detach();
        }
    }

    ThreadRAII(ThreadRAII&&) = default;

    ThreadRAII& operator=(ThreadRAII&&) = default;

    std::thread& get() { return t; }

private:
    DtorAction action;
    std::thread t;
};

int main()
{
    ThreadRAII t{std::thread{[]{}}, ThreadRAII::DtorAction::join};

    t = ThreadRAII{std::thread{[]{}}, ThreadRAII::DtorAction::detach};

    return 0;
}
```

But in the example above, std::terminate is called.

I think that the default move constructor should be ok, but not the move assignment, because the move assignment has to release the current resource before acquiring the new one. Otherwise, the assignment is going to destroy a thread that is joinable, which causes program termination.

I didn't see this issue in the errata list for the book. Is the book really wrong by saying the default move assignment operator should be fine? I would like to be sure and  have other people look at it in order to contact the author.

This is what I think it should have been:

```
#include <thread>

class ThreadRAII
{
public:
    enum class DtorAction { join, detach };

    ThreadRAII(std::thread&& t, DtorAction a)
        : action(a)
        , t(std:: move(t))
    {}

    ~ThreadRAII()
    {
        release();
    }

    ThreadRAII(ThreadRAII&&) = default;

    ThreadRAII& operator=(ThreadRAII&& rhs)
    {
        release();
        action = rhs.action; 
        t = std::move(rhs.t);
        return *this;
    }

    std::thread& get() { return t; }

    void release()
    {
        if(t.joinable())
        {
            if(action == DtorAction::join)
                t.join();
            else
                t.detach();
        }
    }

private:
    DtorAction action;
    std::thread t;
};

int main()
{
    ThreadRAII t{std::thread{[]{}}, ThreadRAII::DtorAction::join};

    t = ThreadRAII{std::thread{[]{}}, ThreadRAII::DtorAction::detach};

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, after reading the example a bit more carefully I deleted my answer. I think it is inconsistent that `operator=` doesn't also try to join/detach if the destructor does so. That doesn't mean it is wrong, just inconsistently designed.

Comment: The move assignment of `std::thread` is specified by the standard to `terminate`, so I don't see a reason why `ThreadRAII` shouldn't do the same.

Comment: Please see [ask]. This title would be ambiguous if there are any other questions related to possible errata in this book.

Comment: Ok, I changed the title to something more specific

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a clear rule of 3(5) violation.

Once you have a custom dtor, you have to make your special assignment and constructors equally custom.  Here, the fact that destroyed threads lead to a join or a detach while assigned to don't is relatively inconsistent.

The writer probably thought about the assinging-to-empty case, and worked out it was fine, and didn't think of the assignging-to-engaged.